# where are we vs where we are

Tags: grammaticality, questions

> 1. Where are we?
> 2. Where we are?

Which one of the above QUESTION is correct?

> 1. I want to know where in the hell are we.
> 2. I want to know where in the hell we are.

Which one of the above STATEMENT is correct?

In the internet, I see both usages in both cases (statement and question). All of them are correct? If not, why?

Comment: It's irrelevant to the question itself, but *where **in the** hell are* isn't a standard idiomatic usage. By far the most common form is [where **the** hell are](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=where+the+hell+are%2Cwhere+in+the+hell+are%2Cwhere+in+hell+are&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), and a distant second is *where **in** hell are*. Using both prepositions ***in*** and ***the*** sounds decidedly odd to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Actually, that's an AmE thing, I think. Check out [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=where+in+the+hell+are%2Cwhere+in+hell+are%2Cwhere+the+hell+are&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), then change the corpus to British English. You'll see the blue line flatten. The more wordy "Where in the hell are we?" _does_ get asked here in the US, [even in print](http://www.google.com/#fp=bf06b3ed3371d569&q=%22where+in+the+hell+are+we%22&tbm=bks).

Comment: @J.R.: oic. So *where **in the** hell* sounds much more "weird" to me because Brits virtually *never* use it. But given that [it didn't originally exist in AmE either](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=where+in+the+hell+are%2Cwhere+in+hell+are&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=), I still think it's probably down to "not-quite-native-speakers" conflating what were originally two distinct idiomatic forms. After enough mis-repeatings, I guess it wouldn't sound so odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be tricky, because of all the variations one can use for a short statement like the ones you are asking about.

For example, if the question is asked as a standalone 3-word question, always use:

> Where are we?

However, if the phrase is used as a clause at the end of a question, one would say:

> Does anybody know where we are?

As for your two statements, either wording can be correct, depending on how you use punctuation:

> I want to know, "Where in the hell are we?"
>   I want to know where in the hell we are!

Answer (score 1):

In English, normal form is Subject-Verb for a statement, and Verb-Subject for a question.

Thus:

> Where are(V) we(S)?

Is the correct form for the question, and

> I want to know where in the hell we(S) are(V).

is correct for the statement.

Comment: But it should be noted that quite often native speakers will combine the two as in:  "What I want to know is, 'Where the hell are we?'"  essentially embedding the question inside the statement.